# logging message from python2.7 to python3.9 vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-logging

I am new to python and trying to port an application from `python2.7` to `python 3.9` and facing a problem in logging the message to a file

I have setup the logging configuration
`logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)`  and

when trying to write the logs to a file , getting errors.

`logging.info ( "CRL_TO_PEM_CMD =",CRL_TO_PEM_CMD )` gives  below error in both 2.7 and 3.9

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

`logging.info ( f"CRL_TO_PEM_CMD ={CRL_TO_PEM_CMD}" )` works fine in 3.9, gives error in 2.7

How to write a statement that works for both 2.7 and 3.9?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `CRL_TO_PEM_CMD` is a string, you can use:

```
logging.info ("CRL_TO_PEM_CMD =" + CRL_TO_PEM_CMD)
```

or if not, you need to cast it to `str` first:

```
logging.info ("CRL_TO_PEM_CMD =" + str(CRL_TO_PEM_CMD))
```

BTW, you can use ***string format*** that supports both Python 2 and 3. It can be used to concatenate every type of data with string.

e.g.

```
logging.info ("CRL_TO_PEM_CMD ={}".format(CRL_TO_PEM_CMD))
```

Comment: Not sure why it is downvoted, but its working for both string and number , am not an expert in python. Cannot upvote :(

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the entire point of the ``logging`` design is that messages are *not* prematurely formatted. Presenting *three* ways to circumvent this design goal and not a single way to use ``logging`` properly is very bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

The default logging style on both Python2 and Python3 is [`%`-formatting aka printf-formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). Use a `%`-style placeholder in the `msg`, and the `logging` module will interpolate the other arguments as needed.

```
logging.info("CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = %s", CRL_TO_PEM_CMD )
```

> [The `msg` is the message format string, and the `args` are the arguments which are merged into msg using the string formatting operator.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

Comment: This looks like derived from `C` , is it how we code in advanced python? Am not an expert in python, as this is close to `C` , i will not have any problem in remembering.

Comment: @IrAM As the name "printf-formatting" implies, this is indeed derived from C. Note that it is *not* advanced or modern Python – since you are asking about the ten year old Python2.7, the answer necessarily precludes modern features.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi, this also works fine.